# How to insert two diffrent values into same field?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to insert two different values into my database.

The field names are same but i want two different values to be saved there.

For Now i have a form which creates Organization. in that i have two fields sales and tech. So i insert Name,last_name,email for sales and tech as well. Now whatever values i get from there i save it to users table and save their id to my organization table.

> First i want insert sales person information and then tech person
>   information and get their id and save it in organization

This is my code:

```
        $this->data['company'] = $this->company_m->get_new();
        $this->data['user'] = $this->secure_m->get_new();
        $rules = $this->company_m->rules_admin;

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {



            $data =$this->secure_m->array_from_post(array('first_name','last_name','email'));

            $sales_id = $this->secure_m->save($data,$id);





            $data =$this->secure_m->array_from_post(array('first_name','last_name','email'));

            $tech_id = $this->secure_m->save($data,$id);





            $data = $this->company_m->array_from_post(array('org_name','dba','addr1','addr2','city','state','country','pin','sales_id','tech_id','tax_number','comment','url'));





            $data['sales_id']= $sales_id;
            $data['tech_id']= $tech_id;

            $this->company_m->save($data, $id); 

            redirect('admin/company');

        }
                                            // Load the view
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/company/add';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->
```

**Array from POST code**

```
public function array_from_post($fields){
    $data = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $this->input->post($field);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Show your code of `$this->secure_m->array_from_post`, I think the problem is there.

Comment: @ksimka added the code

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: @Strawberry i want to insert a row and store its id in $sales and then insert another row in the same table and store that row's id to $tech

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array(
    'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
    'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
    'user_type' => $this->input->post('user_type'),
);

$data = $this->model->inset('table_name', $values);
```

And also use this array to many tables

Comment: Yeah i tried your way for inserting sales but shows blank white screen i guess it an error

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get values from wrong keys. I.e. you have `first_name_sales` and `first_name_tech`, but always read from `first_name`.

Try

```
$data_tech = $this->secure_m->array_from_post(array('first_name_tech','last_name_tech','email_tech','tech'));
// ...    
$data_sales = $this->secure_m->array_from_post(array('first_name_sales','last_name_sales','email_sales','sales'));
// ...
```

Also you should `set_value` from corresponding objects instead of same `$user`. Pass like `$user_tech` and `$user_sales` to view. Smth like

```
$this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', ['user_tech' => $data_tech, 'user_sales' => $data_sales]);
```

Comment: please see the updated code i want to insert two values in tables users with one single form

Comment: And this is exactly what I propose. Now you have form with 6 fields, but 3 of them have same names as 3 others. You must change those names in order to get it work. This is HTML forms basics. Or if you think I'm wrong, please, show final HTML of your form.